# How to make a rubber reduction of elements

Tags: html, css

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy8IZ.jpg) Who knows how to make a rubber reduction of elements when narrowing the page?
I just need the elements to shrink and line up in one column, I don't need to do the adaptation, I'll do it myself ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

HTML:

```
<!-- Trading -->
<div class="main-container-trading">
    <div class="container-modal-row">
        <div class="modal-row-text">модельный ряд lofthaus</div>
        <div class="container-btn-params">
            <div class="btn-params-text">Подбор дома
                <div class="container-svg-icon-params">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="showcase-houses">
        <div class="container-item">
            <div class="item-1"></div>
            <div class="container-details">
                <div class="model-house">Lofthaus R70</div>
                <div class="price-house">4.465.000 ₽
                    <div class="size-house">70м2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container-buttons">
                    <div class="btn-more-detailed">
                        <div class="btn-style-more-detailed">Подробнее</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-presentation">
                        <div class="btn-style-presentation">Презентация
                            <div class="container-svg-icon-pdf">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-item">
            <div class="item-2"></div>
            <div class="container-details">
                <div class="model-house">Lofthaus R70</div>
                <div class="price-house">4.465.000 ₽
                    <div class="size-house">70м2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container-buttons">
                    <div class="btn-more-detailed">
                        <div class="btn-style-more-detailed">Подробнее</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-presentation">
                        <div class="btn-style-presentation">Презентация
                            <div class="container-svg-icon-pdf">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-item">
            <div class="item-3"></div>
            <div class="container-details">
                <div class="model-house">Lofthaus R70</div>
                <div class="price-house">4.465.000 ₽
                    <div class="size-house">70м2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container-buttons">
                    <div class="btn-more-detailed">
                        <div class="btn-style-more-detailed">Подробнее</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-presentation">
                        <div class="btn-style-presentation">Презентация
                            <div class="container-svg-icon-pdf">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-container-trading {
    background-color: #6a6a6a;
    padding-left: 145px;
}

/* MODAL ROW HEADER */
.container-modal-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    border-left: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;

    margin-right: 145px;
    padding: 80px 40px 50px 150px;
}

.modal-row-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    line-height: 83px;
}

.container-btn-params {
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    height: 40px;
    width: 220px;

    border: 1px solid #c8b197;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.btn-params-text {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;

    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 29px;
}

.container-svg-icon-params {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

/* SHOWCASE HOUSES */
.showcase-houses {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;


    border-left: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}

.item-1 {
    width: 536px;
    height: 340px;
    background: url("../images/item-1.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}

.item-2 {
    width: 536px;
    height: 340px;
    background: url("../images/item-2.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}

.item-3 {
    width: 537px;
    height: 340px;
    background: url("../images/item-3.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}

.container-details {
    padding: 35px 40px 40px 40px;
}

.model-house {
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;

    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 49px;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.price-house {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.size-house {
    color: #DE0D0D;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 78px;
}

.container-buttons {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.btn-more-detailed {
    width: 150px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 3px solid #c8b197;
}

.btn-style-more-detailed {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-presentation {
    width: 205px;
    height: 60px;

    background-color: #c8b197;
}

.btn-style-presentation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    gap: 10px;

    color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.container-svg-icon-pdf {
    display: flex;
}
```

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: What is a "rubber reduction"? I can't tell what you are trying to achieve from the question in its current state.

Comment: You first need to learn the difference between **absolute** *and* **relative** *length units* and when to use which. Currently you are using **absolute** units (read: `px`) making it impossible to get anything behave like *rubber*. [MDN: CSS values and units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) and [MDN Tutorial: CSS values and units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Values_and_Units). After that, search online for 'responsive web design'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). It offers functionality to style elements  responsive and there are lots of options. From your question, I assume, the css properties that you are going to need are `flex-direction: column;` and/or `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Also, if you want the elements to shrink while resizing, you need to take a look at [CSS Values and Units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) that are responsive (unlinke `px`) such as `%`, `vw` and `vh`.

Comment: @TopTTeDHbIu-DeJLbFuH4uk You are welcome. If you have any other questions regarding html/css, feel free to ask me in the comments or, if needed, open a new question.

Comment: Thanks! Absolutely! And can I contact you somewhere else besides the forum?

Comment: @TopTTeDHbIu-DeJLbFuH4uk Theres contact info in my profile.